# Why I can't access this api? With axios

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, axios

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU9Up.png)

> Backend

```
    [HttpGet]
    public CustomJsonData LoadSampleVolumeInfo(string sampleId)
    {
        var res = BS.LoadSampleVolumeInfo(sampleId);
        return new CustomJsonData() { data = res };
    }
```

> Vue codes

```
setFocus() {
    this.LoadSampleVolumeInfo();
    // this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.search.focus());
},
LoadSampleVolumeInfo(){
  console.log(this.$api);
    this.$api.project.LoadSampleVolumeInfo(this.sampleId).then(res =>{
        this.loading = false;
        this.samples = res.data.data;
    })
  }
},
```

Please have a look on these codes, when I triggered the calling, it always shows me 404 not found. But I've included the api through codes.

Comment: Where and how is `$api.LoadSampleVolumeInfo` defined?

Comment: Did you set the right base url for axios? E.q. `const instance = axios.create({ baseURL: 'https://localhost:9062/'});`